# Cannot trigger two events in .on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my current working code. There is two events one is `click()` and another is `load()`.

```
<script>
    $(".city,.state,.zip,.layout-slider,.jslider-pointer").click(function(){
        var csrf = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
        var cities = [];
        var states = [];
        var zips = [];
        var price = $("#Slider1").val();
        var area = $("#Slider2").val();
        $(".city:checked").each(function(){
            cities.push($(this).val());
            $("#filter-item-city").html('<b>City: </b>'+cities)
        });
        $(".state:checked").each(function(){
            states.push($(this).val());
            $("#filter-item-state").html('<b>State: </b>'+states)
        });
        $(".zip:checked").each(function(){
            zips.push($(this).val());
            $("#filter-item-zip").html('<b>ZIP Code: </b>'+zips)
        });

        if(cities.length == 0){
            $("#filter-item-city").html('')
        }
        if(states.length == 0){
            $("#filter-item-state").html('')
        }
        if(zips.length == 0){
            $("#filter-item-zip").html('')
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'filter',
            data: {_token:csrf,cities:cities,states:states,zips:zips,price:price,area:area},
            type: 'get'
        }).done(function(e){
            $("#result").html(e);
        });
    })


    $(window).load(function(){
        var csrf = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
        var cities = [];
        var states = [];
        var zips = [];
        var price = $("#Slider1").val();
        var area = $("#Slider2").val();
        $(".city:checked").each(function(){
            cities.push($(this).val());
            $("#filter-item-city").html('<b>City: </b>'+cities)
        });
        $(".state:checked").each(function(){
            states.push($(this).val());
            $("#filter-item-state").html('<b>State: </b>'+states)
        });
        $(".zip:checked").each(function(){
            zips.push($(this).val());
            $("#filter-item-zip").html('<b>ZIP Code: </b>'+zips)
        });

        if(cities.length == 0){
            $("#filter-item-city").html('')
        }
        if(states.length == 0){
            $("#filter-item-state").html('')
        }
        if(zips.length == 0){
            $("#filter-item-zip").html('')
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'filter',
            data: {_token:csrf,cities:cities,states:states,zips:zips,price:price,area:area},
            type: 'get'
        }).done(function(e){
            $("#result").html(e);
        });
    })
</script>
```

The code inside both events are same. So, I tried to use `on()` methods.

```
<script>
    $(".city,.state,.zip,.layout-slider,.jslider-pointer").on("click load", function(){
        //pasted duplicate codes here
    })
</script>
```

After using this jQuery is not working. I want to avoid duplicate codes and make the script cleaner and simple. Please help me to make it cleaner.

Comment: Take the function out, and then pass the function name into `load` and `click`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your event is bound on the window. When you are using `.on`, you omit the window and the HTML elements don't have `load` listener. You should still use `.on` event if you have 2 elements to bind events to since `.click` and `.load` are wrappers of `.on`.

For utilisability, simply declare a named function and use it as handler:

```
function handler(){
    /* Your code */
}

$(".city,.state,.zip,.layout-slider,.jslider-pointer").on( 'click', handler );
$( window ).on( 'load', handler );
```

Comment: `.on('load',handler)` is working but `on( 'click', handler );` is not working. I tried `.click(handler)` too

Comment: It works when I use this `on("click",function(){r()})`. Thanks for answering, I got another answer which one is working too.

Comment: If your code in the question was working, this one should too. Also, the only difference between mine and the one above is the `.ready`, which is not needed if you place the script at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Actually I used `on("click",function(){r()})` that's why another answer worked. And for your information my codes are bottom of the page.

Comment: @smartrahat is the code above the exact code or was it reduced? I'm trying to figure out why you need a wrapper function. Also, if you can give me a pastbin of your updated code, I may be able to help you more.

Comment: The code is exact the same. I don't know why it need `function()`, but it's working.

Comment: However, you answered first and gave me idea of making another function. You can review on my comments and change your answer, I will accept it. Or if you have any better solution or explanation please provide it.

Comment: @smartrahat The only reason I can think of why it doesn't work for the `click`, but does for the `load` event is that you would use it like that : `$('...').on('click', r())`. Where you using it like that? If so, you need to omit the parentheses after the function name. Otherwise, I'm completely lost.

Comment: Holy crap!!! You are right. I was using that `$(".city,.state,.zip,.layout-slider,.jslider-pointer").on("click",faceted());`. Now this one is working `$(".city,.state,.zip,.layout-slider,.jslider-pointer").on("click",faceted);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like that

```
<script>
    function handler() {...}

    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $(".city,.state,.zip,.layout-slider,.jslider-pointer").on('click', handler);
    });
    $(window).on('load', handler);
</script>
```